# How to show additional contact information in t-letter head

Tags: context, context-mkiv, letters

I am working on a letter using the `t-letter` module and have found that only my name and address show in the head layer. Any ideas as to how I can show additional contact information as well?

Here is the content:

```
\usemodule[letter][style=fullblock]

\setupletter
  [fromname={Name},
   fromaddress={Address},
   fromphone={Phone},
   fromfax={Fax}
   fromurl={URL}]

\setupletter
  [toname={Mike Wilson},
   toaddress={Linden street 12\\78569 TeX City}]

\setupletter
  [opening={Dear Reader,},
   closing={Greetings from the Author},
   subject={Step by step guide to write a letter},
   signature={Arthur Thor}]

\startletter
\input knuth\par
\stopletter
```

I've looked through the `t-letter` module source and it looks like it has the ability to display that information, but I'm not sure how to get it to.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
After fiddling with the workings of the `t-letter` module source I figured out that the following will produce the desired output, but the formatting is lost (the head is displaced in a single line with no spaces between the fields):

```
\setupletterlayer[head][alternative=left,fromrule=no]
```

Google searches commenced and I found that it should be `\setupletterstyle`, but when I use that the old head returns. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The following code seems to do the job, although I am not sure it is the "proper" way to do it.

```
\usemodule[letter]

\setupletter
  [fromname={Name},
   fromaddress={Address},
   fromphone={Phone},
   fromfax={Fax},
   fromurl={URL}]

\defineletterelement[layer][head][exp]{%
  \correspondenceparameter{fromname} \crlf
  \correspondenceparameter{fromaddress} \crlf
  \correspondenceparameter{fromphone} \crlf
  \correspondenceparameter{fromfax} \crlf
  \correspondenceparameter{fromurl} \crlf}

\setupletterlayer[head][%
  color=blue,
  alternative=exp]

\setupletter[%
  toname={Mike Wilson},
  toaddress={Linden street 12\\78569 TeX City}]

\setupletter[%
  opening={Dear Reader,},
  closing={Greetings from the Author},
  subject={Step by step guide to write a letter},
  signature={Arthur Thor}]

\startletter
\input knuth\par
\stopletter
```

One can then define the 'layer' named 'address' (ie information for addressee of the letter) in a similar way, using `\defineletterelement`.